# Retrieve multiple array values with extract

Tags: cakephp

```
array(
    [0]=>
        [index1]=>something
        [index2]=>something else
        [index3]=>something more
    [1]=>
        [index1]=>something
        [index2]=>something else
        [index3]=>something more
    [2]=>
        [index1]=>something
        [index2]=>something else
        [index3]=>something more
)
```

EDIT:
So I would like to retrieve the following:

```
array(
    [0]=>
        [index1]=>something
        [index2]=>something else
    [1]=>
        [index1]=>something
        [index2]=>something else
    [2]=>
        [index1]=>something
        [index2]=>something else
)
```

How do I get multiple indexes of the array using the Set::extract function in cakephp?

This retrieves one value:

```
Set::extract($array, '{n}.index1');
```

but I would like to get multiple values ... say, index1 and index2.

I tried statements like the following, to no avail.

```
Set::extract($array, '[{n}.index1, {n}.index2']);
```

**EDIT**

```
    $__pages = Hash::merge(
                    Hash::extract($pages, 'pages.{n}.id'),
                    Hash::extract($pages, 'pages.{n}.title')
                    );
    pr($__pages);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 104
    [3] => Sample Page
    [4] => about us
    [5] => Services
)
```

That doesn't really help me since I still need the association like so:

```
Array(
   [2] => Sample Page
   [4] => About us
   [104] => Services
)
```

I would even be happy with :

```
Array(
   Array(id => 2, title => Sample Page)
   Array(id => 4, title => About Us)
   Array(id => 104, title => Services)
)
```

**ANSWER**
thecodeparadox's answer works for the test code that I provided. Here is the real life code in case someone stumbles here.
In the book it states, "any string literal enclosed in brackets besides {n} and {s}) is interpreted as a regular expression."
This line seemed to be hidden and not very blatant. So knowing this, I simply used regex rules to retrieve the data I needed. I have an array that pulled wordpress posts from an api, I needed to narrow down the results to `id, title`.

```
array(
   posts=>
      0=>
         id => 3
         slug => sample-page
         type => page
         title => Sample Page
         //...and so on 

      1=>
         id => 7
         slug => sample-page-2
         type => page
         title => Sample Page 2
         //...and so on
```

To retrieve just the id and title I added the following line.

```
pr(Set::classicExtract($pages, 'pages.{n}.{(id|title)}'));
```

this gave me:

```
array(
   posts=>
      0=>
         id => 3
         title => Sample Page

      1=>
         id => 7
         title => Sample Page 2
```

DOCUMENTATION: [Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::extract)

Comment: question updated for those who are following.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
            array(
                'index1'=>'something',
                'index2'=>'something else',
                'index3'=>'something more',
            ),
            array(
                'index1'=>'something',
                'index2'=>'something else',
                'index3'=>'something more',
            ),
            array(
                'index1'=>'something',
                'index2'=>'something else',
                'index3'=>'something more',
            )
        );

$output = Set::classicExtract($arr, '{n}.{index[1-2]}');

print_r($output);

// output


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [index1] => something
            [index2] => something else
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [index1] => something
            [index2] => something else
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [index1] => something
            [index2] => something else
        )

)
```

Comment: @Tim Joyce Please test my answer.. and I hope you'll get your desired answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this. You answered my question and led me on the right path to research why this worked and I was able to adapt it to my real life code. I am updating my question with my findings.

Comment: Looks like the set class is depreciated in favor of the Hash class

Answer (score 2):

One way (if you only want to keep a few results):

```
Hash::merge(
    Hash::extract($array, '{n}.index1'),
    Hash::extract($array, '{n}.index2')
);
```

Another way (if you only want to remove a few):

```
Hash::remove($array, '{n}.index3');
```

Comment: I like your first approach here, and I think it's close. I updated my question to provide you with the output I got when doing that. The formatting is just a bit off because I still need the id and title to be an association. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Set::extract($array, '{n}.{s}'); ?

EDIT: If your array dimension is exactly like the one in your answer, you could try array_keys(Set::extract($array, '{n}.{s}'));

Comment: This will return all strings in the array.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I should reword the question, I need the values to come along with the keys.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here... Assuming you have this array:  $array = array(array('index1'=>'something', 'index2'=>'something else', 'index3'=>'something more'), array('index1'=>'something', 'index2'=>'something else', 'index3'=>'something more')); then accesing the keys and values from the subarray is as easy as getting $array[index], no?

Comment: I simplified the array. The array could have potentially hundreds of nested arrays with the same keys. Trying to avoid a foreach loop.

Comment: I understand, but the question is: the keys from the second level array can repeat? like in my example above, where you have index1, index2 and index 3 in the second subarray, too? In this case what exactly do you want to get in the result? You should put an initial array with 2 or 3 subarrays and then an example array to specify the format of the array you want to get as a result

Comment: @TimJoyce you can not 'avoid a foreach', that is what Hash::* uses. Somewhere there will be a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to stick with the `Set` class ? If it doesn't suit your need, why would you absolutely use it and not create your own function ?
You say in one of your comments that you want to avoid `foreach` loops. But the `Set` class methods are full of `foreach` loops themselve. I may miss the point...

Personnaly I would do it simply with a function like this one:

```
function filter_fields($array_to_filter, $fields_to_keep)
{
    foreach($array_to_filter as $i => $sub_array)
    {
        foreach($sub_array as $field => $value)
        {
            if(!in_array($field, $fields_to_keep))
            {
                unset($array_to_filter[$i][$field]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $array_to_filter;
}
```

Here is an example of what it would return:

```
print_r($array_to_filter);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [index1] => abc
            [index2] => def
            [index3] => ghi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [index1] => jkl
            [index2] => mno
            [index3] => poq
        )
)
*/

$filtered_array = filter_fields($array_to_filter, array('index1', 'index3'));

print_r($filtered_array);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [index1] => abc
            [index3] => ghi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [index1] => jkl
            [index3] => poq
        )
)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I said I wanted to avoid a foreach loop, it's because I already know how to do it that way. I was looking for a more "Cake" way of doing this. I feel the new cakephp documentation for 2.x is lacking in many ways and hoping someone has the answer. Since my migration to 2.x I have google searched most of my problems because of the lack of documentation. The api is great but the cookbook is not.

Comment: I believe you that you know how to do it yourself :-) But if the Cake libraries can't, that is yet another reason to create your own function.

Comment: This can all be done in a single line, $filtered = Hash::remove($array, '{n}.index3');

Comment: If we want to discard only one field, that's true. But with many more fields Hash::remove() would have to be called many times, which would be less performent.

Answer (score 1):

Set is AWESOME! You can't do this directly with Set::extract, but you CAN build an associative array of the the two array indexes using Set::combine:

```
Set::combine($myArray, '{n}.index1', '{n}.index2')
```

A working example looks like this:

```
$myArray = array(
    array('index1'=>'something 1', 'index2'=>'something else 1', 'index3'=>'something more 1'),
    array('index1'=>'something 2', 'index2'=>'something else 2', 'index3'=>'something more 2'),
    array('index1'=>'something 3', 'index2'=>'something else 3', 'index3'=>'something more 3'),
);

debug(Set::combine($myArray, '{n}.index1', '{n}.index2'));
```

This will take an array like you mentioned:

```
array(
[0]=>
    [index1]=>something 1
    [index2]=>something else 1
    [index3]=>something more 1
[1]=>
    [index1]=>something 2
    [index2]=>something else 2
    [index3]=>something more 2
[2]=>
    [index1]=>something 3
    [index2]=>something else 3
    [index3]=>something more 3
```

)

and turn it into this:

```
Array (
    [something1] => something else 1
    [something2] => something else 2
    [something3] => something else 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[ +10 ] Big thumbs up for revealing the classicExtract method to me in this post.

Example array:

```
$params = array(
  'key-1'=>array('subkey'=>array('x'), 'junk'), 
  'key-2'=>array('subkey'=>array('y'), 'otherkey'=>'more junk')
);
```

The problem i had:

The base key gets converted to int.

```
 eg. array(0=>array('x'), 1=>array('y'))
```

Solution:

```
$array = Hash::filter(Set::classicExtract($params, '{[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]}.subkey'));
```

returns:

```
eg. array('key-1'=>array('x'), 'key-2'=>array('y'))
```

Modify regex in key as needed.

Just wrote this function

It will give the ability to parse array by using {a) instead of {s}

{a} for associative key for base.

called like so: static::extract($array, '{a}.subkey');

```
  public static function extract($array, $path, $filter=true){
    $path = str_replace("{a}", "{[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]}", $path);
    if(is_array($array)){
      $return = Set::classicExtract($array, $path);
      if($filter){
        if(is_array($return)){
          $return = Hash::filter($return);
        }
      }
      return $return;
    }
  }
```

**[[ UPDATE FOR CAKE 3 ]]**

**If you were using this function I see cakephp just removed the set class. You can get it to work again by adding the classicExtract method to you class**

```
use Cake\Utility\Hash;

public static function classicExtract($data, $path = null)
{
    if (empty($path)) {
        return $data;
    }
    if (is_object($data)) {
        if (!($data instanceof \ArrayAccess || $data instanceof \Traversable)) {
            $data = get_object_vars($data);
        }
    }
    if (empty($data)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (is_string($path) && strpos($path, '{') !== false) {
        $path = \Cake\Utility\String::tokenize($path, '.', '{', '}');
    } elseif (is_string($path)) {
        $path = explode('.', $path);
    }
    $tmp = array();

    if (empty($path)) {
        return null;
    }

    foreach($path as $i => $key) {
        if (is_numeric($key) && intval($key) > 0 || $key === '0') {
            if (isset($data[$key])) {
                $data = $data[$key];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } elseif ($key === '{n}') {
            foreach($data as $j => $val) {
                if (is_int($j)) {
                    $tmpPath = array_slice($path, $i + 1);
                    if (empty($tmpPath)) {
                        $tmp[] = $val;
                    } else {
                        $tmp[] = static::classicExtract($val, $tmpPath);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $tmp;
        } elseif ($key === '{s}') {
            foreach($data as $j => $val) {
                if (is_string($j)) {
                    $tmpPath = array_slice($path, $i + 1);
                    if (empty($tmpPath)) {
                        $tmp[] = $val;
                    } else {
                        $tmp[] = static::classicExtract($val, $tmpPath);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $tmp;
        } elseif (strpos($key, '{') !== false && strpos($key, '}') !== false) {
            $pattern = substr($key, 1, -1);

            foreach($data as $j => $val) {
                if (preg_match('/^'.$pattern.'/s', $j) !== 0) {
                    $tmpPath = array_slice($path, $i + 1);
                    if (empty($tmpPath)) {
                        $tmp[$j] = $val;
                    } else {
                        $tmp[$j] = static::classicExtract($val, $tmpPath);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $tmp;
        } else {
            if (isset($data[$key])) {
                $data = $data[$key];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

//CAKEPHP METHODS
public static function extract($array, $path, $filter = true)
{
    $return = [];
    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (stristr($path, '{a}')) {
            $return = static::classicExtract($array, str_replace("{a}", "{[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]}", $path));
        } else {
            $return = Hash::extract($array, $path);
        }
    }
    if ($filter && is_array($return)) {
        $return = Hash::filter($return);
    }
    return $return;
}
```